# Cannot download the video clip from kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis-video-streams, amazon-kinesis

I am using the below code, in order to download the clip. I have successfully received the response and I am trying to download the video but I cannot be able.

```
const completeUrl = url + "/getClip";

const res = await client.post(completeUrl, params, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
            "X-Amz-Target": "CodeBuild_20161006.StartBuild",
          },
        });
    
console.log("axios signedRquest is ", res);


   var binaryData: any = [];
        binaryData.push(res.data);

        const downloadElement = document.createElement("a");
        const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob(binaryData, { type: contentType })
        );
        downloadElement.href = href;
        downloadElement.download = "test.mp4";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadElement);
        downloadElement.click();
        document.body.removeChild(downloadElement);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by just adding the  `responseType: "blob"`  in the request

```
const res = await client.post(completeUrl, params, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
            "X-Amz-Target": "CodeBuild_20161006.StartBuild",
          },
          responseType: "blob", // added this line
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

### In case someone get here...

### This works!

```
export const downloadStream = async function (stream, timeStampStart, length) {


var streamName = stream.id;
const credentials = await Auth.currentCredentials();
var params = {
    credentials: credentials,
    region: "us-east-1"
}

const timeStampEnd = timeStampStart + (length * 60 * 1000);


//get endpoint first
const kinesisVideo = new KinesisVideoClient(params);

params["APIName"] = "GET_CLIP";
params["StreamName"] = streamName;

const endPCommand = new GetDataEndpointCommand(params);


await kinesisVideo
    .send(endPCommand)
    .then((data) => {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        params["endpoint"] = data.DataEndpoint;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    .finally(() => {
        // finally.
    });



const kinesisVideoArchived = new KinesisVideoArchivedMedia(params);

const dnlparams = {


    StreamName: streamName,

    ClipFragmentSelector: {
        FragmentSelectorType: ClipFragmentSelectorType.PRODUCER_TIMESTAMP,
        TimestampRange: {

            StartTimestamp: new Date(timeStampStart),
            EndTimestamp: new Date(timeStampEnd)
        }
    },
};

const dnlCommand = new GetClipCommand(dnlparams);

//getClip

await kinesisVideoArchived
    .send(dnlCommand)
    .then(async (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        const link = document.createElement("a");

        const byt = await data.Payload.transformToByteArray();

        const file = new Blob([byt], { type: 'video/mp4' });

        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        link.download = "clip.mp4";
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
  
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
    .finally(() => {
        // finally.
    });
```

}

Comment: Getting credentials through Amplify Auth...

Answer (score 0):

For Anyone who has been stuck on this and want's a simple end to end solution using python. What the code is doing:

- Initializing boto3 libraries for Kinesis Video Stream
- Getting the endpoint URL from where you can communicate
  with the video.
- Initialized chunk as the GetClip API of Kinesis video
  stream has limitation of 100MB or 200 fragments at a
  time.
- Starting a loop and determining the start and end time
  and the loop will continue till the stream has reached
  the end time

Below is the code:

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Initialize AWS SDK
    session = boto3.Session()
    client = session.client('kinesis-video-archived-media')
    kvs = session.client('kinesisvideo')

    # Obtain the endpoint using GetDataEndpoint
    get_data_endpoint_response = kvs.get_data_endpoint(
        StreamName='<Your-stream-name>',
        APIName='GET_CLIP'
    )

    # Extract the endpoint
    endpoint = get_data_endpoint_response['DataEndpoint']

    # Create a new client using the obtained endpoint
    client = session.client('kinesis-video-archived-media', endpoint_url=endpoint)

    # Specify the stream name and timestamp range for the clip
    stream_name = '<Your-stream-name>'
    start_timestamp = datetime(2023, 5, 2, 7, 9, 50)    #example values you can adjust this according to your stream
    end_timestamp = datetime(2023, 5, 2, 7, 10, 59)     #example values you can adjust this according to your stream
    chunk_size = 85 * 1024 * 1024  # 85 MB chunks    #using this as the getClip API has limit of 100MB or 200 fragments

    # Initialize variables
    current_timestamp = start_timestamp
    clip_data = b''
    clip_number = 1
    reached_end = False 

    while current_timestamp < end_timestamp:
        # Calculate the end timestamp for the current chunk
        chunk_end_timestamp = current_timestamp + timedelta(minutes=5)
        if chunk_end_timestamp > end_timestamp:
            chunk_end_timestamp = end_timestamp

        try:

            # Call the get_clip API to retrieve the video clip for the current chunk
            response = client.get_clip(
                StreamName=stream_name,
                ClipFragmentSelector={
                    'FragmentSelectorType': 'SERVER_TIMESTAMP',
                    'TimestampRange': {
                        'StartTimestamp': current_timestamp,
                        'EndTimestamp': chunk_end_timestamp
                    }
                }
            )

            # Read the current chunk of data
            chunk_data = response['Payload'].read()
            clip_data += chunk_data
            

            # Check if the chunk is less than 100 MB or if we've reached the end timestamp
            if len(chunk_data) < chunk_size:
                # Upload the current chunk to S3
                s3_bucket_name = '<Your-s3-bucket-name>'
                s3_object_key = f'video-{stream_name}/{stream_name}-{clip_number}-{start_timestamp}-{end_timestamp}.mp4'
                s3_client = session.client('s3')
                s3_client.put_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=s3_object_key, Body=chunk_data)

                # Reset clip_data for the next chunk
                clip_data = b''
                clip_number += 1

            # Move to the next chunk
            current_timestamp = chunk_end_timestamp

            # Check if we've reached the end timestamp
            if current_timestamp >= end_timestamp:
                reached_end = True
                break

        except client.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundException:
            # If no fragments are found, sleep for a while and retry
            time.sleep(2)
            continue

    if reached_end:
        return f"Video clip parts have been stored in S3."
    else:
        return "Video processing completed, but the end timestamp was not reached."
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**